# How can I remove a taskbar icon but keep it running?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, desktop-customization

I want to remove the taskbar icon not just hide it in the overflow but keep it running in the background. The app doesn't have an option to hide its taskbar icon.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding the entry on the taskbar, you could minimize the
application to the tray bar. This will save space on the taskbar,
and you may undo it at any time.

Some applications that might help:

- [TrayIt!](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/TrayIt.shtml)
- [4t Tray Minimizer](https://www.4t-niagara.com/tray.html)
- [MinimizeToTray](https://github.com/sandwichdoge/MinimizeToTray)
- [Auto Window Manager](https://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)